# Excel sparklines printing issue

Tags: excel, excel-2010, sparklines

In an Excel 2010 document with more than one page of records, where each row includes a sparkline, the sparklines do not print or appear in print preview unless one first scrolls through the entire document to view all lines.  In my application that produces a series of Excel reports automatically, this is a very visible issue.  Can anyone suggest a fix for this or is this a bug in Excel 2010?

Comment: I have a similar issue. For details see [this StackOverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204830/excel-sparklines-not-exported-to-pdf-when-using-com-automation).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an annoying workaround, but you could put a simple macro in that workbook that runs whenever the workbook is opened that simply scrolls to the bottom of the workbook and then back to the top. ;-)

Let me know if you would need help creating that.